# Android CountDownTimer onTick method not called

Tags: android, countdowntimer

I have this code in Android

```
private void startStageTwoTimer(long timeUntilStageTwo) {
        timer = new CountDownTimer(timeUntilStageTwo, 1000) {
            public void onFinish() {
                timer.cancel();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                Log.v("millisUntilFinished", millisUntilFinished + "");
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:MM:ss", Locale.getDefault());
                calendar.setTimeInMillis(millisUntilFinished);
                textView.setText(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
            }
        }.start();
    }
```

where "timeUntilStageTwo" is time until some hour in next day, so I want to make it on every second (in the onTick method) to refresh the textView and change its text.
The problem is this onTick method is called just few times, and then stops being called at all, why is that? The point is I want to make a timer in the activity, that counts untill the given hour

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I should have noticed that immediately. Still, why do you think your Activity will remain visible for whole day?

Comment: what value do you start the method with

Comment: what do you mean what value, and which method?

Comment: can you give an example value of `timeUntilStageTwo` that you pass to `startStageTwoTimer` ?

Comment: right now the value is 60546809

Comment: your code works for me. have you checked the debug messages?

Comment: yes, there is nothing wrong there, I put a Log.v in the onFinish, and it is never executed, the onTick method just stops at some point and thats it

Comment: omg I am dumb, the problem was that I have been using just one CountDownTimer, and it is being canceled when the onTouch is released, so thats why it was stopping.......

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that `timeUntilStageTwo` is **milliseconds** and **not seconds**.

So in case you need the timer to run for one hour, `timeUntilStageTwo` should be **3.600.000**